# Why is entity framework not respecting my data annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Why is entity framework not respecting my data annotations?

A little background: I just started a new job and I'm tasked with adding entity framework to an ASP.net project. The project structure is as follows:
    Data.csproj -> has my newly added code-first entity framework code. This project will house our models
    MVC.csproj -> ClassLibrary that houses all the controllers for our MVC structure. This project is currently riddled with MVC areas. I've added OWIN along with a UserStore, UserManager, and SignInManager
    Web.vbproj -> This is/was an Asp.Net web forms project that has a mix of MVC and webforms code. Accoring to my boss, the system architect, the plan is to have nothing in this project except html views, css, and javascript. We our currently migrating this project from asp.net webforms to the aforementioned MVC structure.

I'm using EntityFramework v6.1.1

In the Data.csproj project I have the following entity defined:

```
[Table("Terminals", Schema = "dbo")]
public class TerminalEx
{
    #region Constructors
    public TerminalEx()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    [Key]
    public int TerminalId { get; set; }

    public string License { get; set; }

    [Column("TerminalName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string RootPublicDomainAddress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string DispatchEmail { get; set; }

    [Column("useAutoAddlDrvPmt")]
    public byte UseAutoAddDriverPayment { get; set; }

    public byte UseTerminalAutoAssignment { get; set; }
    public byte UseMapCodes { get; set; }

    [Column("OEautoPopulateAccountNo")]
    public byte AutoPopulateAccountNumberForOrderEntry { get; set; }

    [Column("OEautoPopulateAddresses")]
    public byte AutoPopulateAddressesForOrderEntry { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

and here is my DbContext:

```
public class XceleratorContext : DbContext
{
    public static void DoTest()
    {
        XceleratorContext db = null;
        try
        {
            db = new XceleratorContext();
            var bleh = db.Terminals.ToList();

            foreach (TerminalEx term in bleh)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(term.TerminalId);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(term.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (db != null)
            {
                db.Dispose();
                db = null;
            }
        }
    }

    #region Contructors
    public XceleratorContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"])
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<XceleratorContext>(null);
        this.Database.Log += WriteLog;
    }

    private void WriteLog(string obj)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(obj);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public virtual DbSet<TerminalEx> Terminals { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Encapsulation of DbSets
    public T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
    }

    public T Detach<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
        return entity;
    }

    public T Remove<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        if (Entry<T>(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            return Entry<T>(entity).Entity;
        }
        else
            return Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Method Overrides
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EFUser>();
        var terminalConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<TerminalEx>();

        //terminalConfig.Map(b => 
        //{
        //    b.Property(c => c.Name).HasColumnName("TerminalName");
        //    b.Property(c => c.UseAutoAddDriverPayment).HasColumnName("useAutoAddlDrvPmt");
        //    b.Property(c => c.AutoPopulateAccountNumberForOrderEntry).HasColumnName("OEautoPopulateAccountNo");
        //    b.Property(c => c.AutoPopulateAddressesForOrderEntry).HasColumnName("OEautoPopulateAddresses");                
        //}).ToTable("Terminals", "dbo").HasKey(d => d.TerminalId);

        // base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }        
    #endregion

    #region Stored Proicedure Calls
    public IEnumerable<EFUser> GetUser(int? id = null, string userName = null, string passwordHash = null)
    {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<EFUser>(
            " exec dbo.GetUser @id, @userName, @passwordHash ", 
            GetSqlParameter("id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, value: id),
            GetSqlParameter("userName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, userName),
            GetSqlParameter("passwordHash", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, passwordHash));            
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private static SqlParameter GetSqlParameter<T>(string name, System.Data.SqlDbType type, int? size = null, T? value = null) where T : struct
    {
        var res = new SqlParameter(name, type) { Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value };

        if (size.HasValue)
            res.Size = size.Value;

        return res;
    }

    private static SqlParameter GetSqlParameter(string name, System.Data.SqlDbType type, int size, string value)
    {
        return new SqlParameter(name, type, size) { Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and finally inside Web.vbproj here is Page_Load of index.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Xcelerator.Data.BizObjects.XceleratorContext.DoTest()

End Sub
```

My problem is that I get the following error. I've tested my code by creating a new asp.net webforms VB proj and calling the same method on page load of the index page and that works fine. I've removed as much code, references, and packages as possible from the web.vbpoj but I still get the same error. For some reason in this Web.vbproj only, code-first entity framework is not respecting my data annotations.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was caught
>   HResult=-2146232004   Message=An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__2()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__1()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>          at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>          at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>          at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at Xcelerator.Data.BizObjects.XceleratorContext.DoTest() in c:\svonaRepo\XceleratorLocal -
>   Copy\Xcelerator.Data\BizObjects\XceleratorContext.cs:line 22
>   InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>          HResult=-2146232060
>          Message=Invalid object name 'dbo.TerminalExes'.
>          Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>          ErrorCode=-2146232060
>          Class=16
>          LineNumber=1
>          Number=208
>          Procedure=""
>          Server=KSS-DT18
>          State=1
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The Web.vbproj project had the NuGet packages folder included in the project. by excluding the folder from the project, my EF code/method works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code says, "I want to do Fluent Code First with POCOs" which is to say, my POCOs have no annotations, here is the mapping customizations I want.

You then proceed to make NO customizations to the mapping. Therefore you get the default mappings.

```
#region Method Overrides
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EFUser>();
    var terminalConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<TerminalEx>();

    //terminalConfig.Map(b => 
    //{
    //    b.Property(c => c.Name).HasColumnName("TerminalName");
    //    b.Property(c => c.UseAutoAddDriverPayment).HasColumnName("useAutoAddlDrvPmt");
    //    b.Property(c => c.AutoPopulateAccountNumberForOrderEntry).HasColumnName("OEautoPopulateAccountNo");
    //    b.Property(c => c.AutoPopulateAddressesForOrderEntry).HasColumnName("OEautoPopulateAddresses");                
    //}).ToTable("Terminals", "dbo").HasKey(d => d.TerminalId);

    // base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}        
#endregion
```

Just remove that part of your `DbContext` and everything should be fine.

Comment: You're telling me to remove the override to OnModelCreating? I don't think this is correct since the same code works when I call `XceleratorContext.DoTest()` from my asp.net vb test project. I've found that I need to call `modelBuilder.Entity<ClassName>()` even if I'm not using the fluent API

Comment: @scottKSS Sounds like you didnt even try it out. If so there is no point in me trying to help you.

Comment: sorry if I sounded like I was blowing you off. I wasn't. I did not try it because I know from past experience that if you do not define your entities in the model builder then you cannot perform CRUD operations on them. 

Maybe I don't know enough about EF. If I declare TerminalEx with `public virtual DbSet<TerminalEx> Terminals { get; set; }` can I avoid defining it in OnModelCreating? What about `EFUser`? I don't have a DbSet defined for that. I'm encapsulating my DbSet in general. I just exposed a DbSet for TerminalEx so I didnt have to define a Get method for it.